# OpenLayers plugin in QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.10

I've installed QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa on my PC, but I don't have the OpenLayers option in the plugin section (Módulos). And also not appear in the Web section. I've uninstalled it and installed back the QGIS, but this option is not there! I really need this tool to my work. Please help me!

[image: Plugin section print screen]
[image: Web section print screen]

Comment: Are you installing from the QGIS standalone installer or from the OSGeo4W installer?

Comment: As mentioned by @DirkBrunken in his answer, you can try manually downloading and extracting the [OpenLayers](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/) plugin to the `C:\Users\you\.qgis2\python\plugins` directory.

Comment: To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces: This will be displayed in a monospaced font. The first four spaces will be stripped off, but all other whitespace will be preserved. Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks: <i>This is not italic</i>, and [this is not a link](https://example.com)
To create not a block, but an inline code span, use backticks: The `$` character is just a shortcut for `window.jQuery`.
If you want to have a preformatted block within a list, indent by eight spaces: 1. This is normal text.
2. So is this, but now follows a code block: Sk

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145448)

Answer (score 1):

you can go to configurations and set the plugin repository to download and install the openlayer plugin manually by yourself.

also here is the website to download plugins --> https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/
[image: Plugin-Repository]